# How to validate the select option in my contact form?

Tags: javascript, html

Why it's not validating my select option in my contact form?
I've tried to use this js code but it's not worked for the select one, it's worked only with the input and the textarea.
What I Need to change here to make it work?
Thanks for helpers.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('select').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if( ! action ) {
      action = 'mail/mail.php';
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $('#hide-button').addClass("hide");
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $('#hide-button').removeClass("hide");
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name*" name="name" id="name" data-rule="minlen:3" data-msg="Please enter at least 3 chars">
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email*" name="email" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid Email">
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number*" name="tel" id="tel" data-rule="minlen:10" data-msg="Please enter a valid Phone Number">
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <select class="form-control" name="service" id="service" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please select a service">
            <option selected disabled value="Select Service">Select Service</option>
            <option value="Bathroom Remodeling">Bathroom Remodeling</option>
            <option value="Kitchen Remodeling">Kitchen Remodeling</option>
            <option value="New Renovation/Construction">New Renovation/Construction</option>
            <option value="Luxury Home">Luxury Home</option>
          </select>
        <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" name="address" id="address">
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="hide-button" class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Now</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 text-center mt-4">
        <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        <div id="errormessage">Sorry! Something went wrong. Try again.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you've got a syntax error that you need to fix first. Then you need to reference JQuery, and then you've got to wrap all that JS in a function and call it from somewhere.

Comment: I updated the code can you look on it now?

Comment: You still have at least one syntax error, which you can see here by clicking the Run code snippet button as well as when you look at the developer's tools console in your browser. Fix your syntax first.

Comment: None of your options have a value of empty string,

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was look on it and still didn't find the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to fix it:

```
function JSFunctionValidate() {
if(document.getElementById('service').selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert("Please select service");
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Let me know.

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Just saying "use this to fix it" is not an answer. You should point out what, in the OPs code was wrong and why and then explain how/why your suggestion fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `select` already has a non-empty value selected and therefore the error condition isn't triggered. Your page has:

```
<option selected disabled value="Select Service">Select Service</option>
```

Set the `value` attribute to an empty string:

```
<option selected disabled value="">Select Service</option>
```

Comment: but I don't want it selectable, I just want it as a placeholder, should I need to use something else?

Comment: It's not `selectable` by the user if it's marked `disabled`.

Comment: Got it thank you, but it's still didn't fix may validation issue. any advice?